# The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, ios7.1

I had generate the keys (developer.facebook.com) for my iOS application. I had integrate the fb sdk to my application, It can access only with my account. Other user cannot login. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Thanks for Advance

```
 Error - App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.
```

Note: Below had attached the screenshots for your reference. I can't enable the general public option.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must got to your developer account on Facebook.  From there click on your app and go to `Status & Review`.  Then set `Public` to `YES`.

EDIT:

If hen trying to turn app public it asks for a `contact email` go to the settings page for your app on face books developer site and type your email address into the contact email field and save the new settings.

Comment: You must specify a contact email.  From the developer account click your app and the click settings.  There you will see a place to put a contact email. Add yours and you should be good to go. Don't forget to save your changes at the bottom after you enter your email as well.